# python sqlite3 DELETE FROM table row if exists

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python script that inserts rows into a table. I want it to either delete duplicate rows or ignore the INSERT if the row exists. What I have tried so far:

```
#delete duplicate entries
c.execute('''DELETE FROM server WHERE sites NOT IN
            (SELECT MIN(sites) sites FROM server GROUP BY sites)''')
```

The table "server" is a single column "sites". This is a table of web sites. It's not throwing any errors. It's just doesn't not deleting the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing against the `sites` itself does not help, because the duplicates have the same value in this column.

You have to use some other column that is unique. In this case, you could use the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

```sql
DELETE FROM server
WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT min(rowid)
                    FROM server
                    GROUP BY sites);
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks.